# Query with OR making query execution SLOW

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, conditional-statements

I am a newbie and have trouble with a OR query!

When I do it without OR the execution time is: 0.02 Seconds

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
                ht.html_title,
                ht.html_content,
                sc.sub_cat_name,
                sc.main_cat_id,
                us.username,
                c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p,
       ad_html ht,
       ad_catagory_sub sc,
       ad_user us,
       ad_cities c
WHERE  ( ht.ad_id = p.id )
       AND ( sc.sub_cat_id = p.category )
       AND ( us.id = p.user_id )
       AND ( p.category = 216 )
       AND ( p.status = 'active' )
       AND ( c.id = p.city )
       AND ( p.city = 135 )
ORDER  BY p.created_at DESC;
```

And when I am trying it with OR condition then it takes about 4.70 Seconds

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
                ht.html_title,
                ht.html_content,
                sc.sub_cat_name,
                sc.main_cat_id,
                us.username,
                c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p,
       ad_html ht,
       ad_catagory_sub sc,
       ad_user us,
       ad_cities c
WHERE  ( ht.ad_id = p.id )
       AND ( sc.sub_cat_id = p.category )
       AND ( us.id = p.user_id )
       AND ( p.category = 216
              OR p.parent_category = 216 )
       AND ( p.status = 'active' )
       AND ( c.id = p.city )
       AND ( p.city = 135 )
ORDER  BY p.created_at DESC;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type        | possible_keys                                                                  | key                      | key_len | ref                       | rows  | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | const       | PRIMARY                                                                        | PRIMARY                  | 4       | const                     |     1 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | index_merge | PRIMARY,id,parent_category,city,user_id_2,category,status,id_2,id_3,category_2 | category,parent_category | 4,4     | NULL                      | 67889 |     4.74 | Using union(category,parent_category); Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sc    | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                        | PRIMARY                  | 4       | abc_classified.p.category |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | us    | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                                                                        | PRIMARY                  | 4       | abc_classified.p.user_id  |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ht    | NULL       | ref         | ad_id                                                                          | ad_id                    | 4       | abc_classified.p.id       |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I think I have proper indexes defined, can someone point out what am i doing wrong ? or how can i decrease execution time ? Also why this is happening for my knowledge ?

Comment: Please format your queries onto multiple lines so that we may read them.

Comment: the `union` solution should work and btw you can call both tables `p` there is no need to change the top query to p1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dwight Reynoldson Answers works just fine on SQL Server and I got a workaround for "ORDER BY" issue on MySQL. All I did was `ORDER BY created_at DESC` instead of `ORDER BY p.created_at DESC` It was the p which was creating all the issue.

Answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.*,
        ht.html_title,
        ht.html_content,
        sc.sub_cat_name,
        sc.main_cat_id,
        us.username,
        c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p1 inner join ad_html ht on ht.ad_id = p1.id
    inner join ad_category_sub sc on sc.sub_cat_id = p1.category
    inner join ad_user us on  us.id = p1.user_id 
    inner join ad_cities c on c.id = p1.city   
WHERE ( p1.status = 'active' )
   AND ( p1.city = 135 )
   AND ( p1.category = 216)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
        ht.html_title,
        ht.html_content,
        sc.sub_cat_name,
        sc.main_cat_id,
        us.username,
        c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p 
    inner join ad_html ht on ht.ad_id = p.id
    inner join ad_category_sub sc on sc.sub_cat_id = p.category
    inner join ad_user us on us.id = p.user_id
    inner join ad_cities c on c.id = p.city
WHERE ( p.status = 'active' )
  AND ( p.city = 135 )
  AND (p.parent_category = 216)
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your query would benefit from a union rather than an or.
This creates 2 sets of data. One on the categoryid and the other on the parent categoryid. Which will be quicker than defining 2 negative sets. One set without the categoryid = 216 and one without the parent categoryid = 216.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.*,
        ht.html_title,
        ht.html_content,
        sc.sub_cat_name,
        sc.main_cat_id,
        us.username,
        c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p1 inner join ad_html ht on ht.ad_id = p1.id
    inner join ad_category_sub sc on sc.sub_cat_id = p1.category
    inner join ad_user us on  us.id = p1.user_id 
    inner join ad_cities c on c.id = p1.city   
WHERE ( p1.status = 'active' )
   AND ( p1.city = 135 )
   AND ( p1.category = 216)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT p.*,
        ht.html_title,
        ht.html_content,
        sc.sub_cat_name,
        sc.main_cat_id,
        us.username,
        c.name AS cityname
FROM   ad_product p 
    inner join ad_html ht on ht.ad_id = p.id
    inner join ad_category_sub sc on sc.sub_cat_id = p.category
    inner join ad_user us on us.id = p.user_id
    inner join ad_cities c on c.id = p.city
WHERE ( p.status = 'active' )
  AND ( p.city = 135 )
  AND (p.parent_category = 216)
ORDER  BY p.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Reynoldson Thanks for the answer. I tried executing the query and got an error:  
"#1250 - Table 'p' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list"

I don't understand what does it says, may be you can help!

Comment: Hi Aarav, I think that error is being caused by the same alias "p" being used in the top and bottom half of the query. I've edited the query in the code example so that "p1" is used in the top half. Try that and let me know how you get on. If still no joy I'll need to build a mini version of your data structures to test the query.

Comment: Hi Reynoldson, thanks for the edit but it gives the same error " #1250 - Table 'p' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list" I even tried by changing p to p2 but no luck.

Comment: Hi Aarav, I've edited the code block again. This does not error for me (I'm working with a test data structure and this is written in SQL server so may need translating to mysql if you are using mysql). I've essentially replaced most of the where clauses with joins (which is what the optimizer would do anyway) and I'm still utilizing the union to avoid the or operator issue. I hope this gets you closer.

Comment: Hey Reynoldson, Thanks for the solution with optimization. It worked but without "ORDER BY" as it was throwing the same "#1250" Error. After searching a while I got https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68529 which shows there is some bug when we use "ORDER BY" with UNION or GROUP BY. I am still searching for the solution with ORDER BY but this will do. 
Thanks a lot for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

When you define exact values in where conditions, SQL uses a `hash join`. So it is much more faster than other joins. When you change it to a non exact value condition ( X OR Y ), it becomes slow.

The solution is to make an `index` in order to decrease the records to be searched.

Comment: I have already defined index on both "category" and parent_category individually. Please have a look at the EXPLAIN result  I have posted, It shows that the query with "OR" is already using index.